# Oracle scheduler error: Security Group ID (your workspace identity) is invalid

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am trying to create oracle scheduler job (send mail) by pl/sql process (job is created on button click). It create job successfully but job always finish with error:

> **"ORA-20001: Security Group ID (your workspace identity) is invalid. ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_SECURITY", line 2939 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_050100.HTMLDB_UTIL", line 3014 ORA-06512: at line 7 ORA-06512:
>   at line 7**.

I also have tried to set security_group_id directly  (`apex_util.set_security_group_id(p_security_group_id => my_worspace_id` or 
  `wwv_flow_api.set_security_group_id(p_security_group_id=>my_worspace_id`) but it always finish with the same error as my sample code. When i try to create job manually in sql developer it works. But when job is created by pl/sql process it finish with the mentioned error. Job is created successfully in both cases (pl/sql process or manually) with the same parameters so i do not understand why in case when job is created by pl/sql process it finish with error.

```
    BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
            job_name => '"INVERTORY"."TEST"',
            job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
            job_action => 'begin
for c1 in (
   select workspace_id
     from apex_applications
    where application_id = 104 )
loop
   apex_util.set_security_group_id(p_security_group_id =>
c1.workspace_id);
end loop;

HTMLDB_MAIL.SEND(
               p_to =>  ''****.****@****.com'',
               p_from => ''noreply@****.com'',
               p_subj =>  ''test mail'',
               p_body => ''komu'');

            end;',
            number_of_arguments => 0,
            start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2017-08-28 10:29:57.000000000 EUROPE/PRAGUE','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR'),
            repeat_interval => NULL,
            end_date => NULL,
            enabled => TRUE,
            auto_drop => FALSE,
            comments => '');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"INVERTORY"."TEST"', 
             attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
             name => '"INVERTORY"."TEST"');
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this :

```
for c1 in (
   select workspace_id
     from apex_applications
    where application_id = 104 )
loop
   apex_util.set_security_group_id(p_security_group_id =>
c1.workspace_id);
end loop;
```

To this :

```
  SELECT MAX(workspace_id) 
  INTO v_workspace FROM apex_applications
  WHERE application_id = 104;
 --set workspace - declare v_workspace above as type number
  wwv_flow_api.set_security_group_id(v_workspace)
```

In any event, it would be better to put your logic in a package in the database and create a job with `job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'` and call on your procedure from there.

Comment: I have tried it but i got error : ORA-20001: This procedure must be invoked from within an application session.
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_MAIL", line 595
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_MAIL", line 621
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_MAIL", line 654
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_MAIL_API", line 47
ORA-06512: at line 17

Comment: Don't have time to reply right now, but this thread may help - https://community.oracle.com/thread/3998543

Comment: Also, try using `apex_mail.send` instead of `HTMLDB_MAIL.SEND`, followed by `apex_mail.push_queue();`

Comment: I have created procedure to send mail and in job i only call this procedure.  This works. Thank you.